# Flatpak download size

Tags: 18.04, flatpak

I [added Flatpak support](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu/) to my Ubuntu 18.04 and I'm confused about the package details it's showing me.

For example for GIMP package, it shows me it needs to download 1.4 GB in order to install 213 MB of the app.

[image]

For other applications (Android Studio) it wants download more than 5 GB just for one application. This is insane in my opinion.

**Is this Flatpak / Ubuntu Software Center bug or just my misunderstanding?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always have a choice between official APT repositories and third-party ones and/or [PPAs](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas). For example GIMP has [a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp).

[Snaps](https://snapcraft.io/store) and [Flatpaks](https://flathub.org/apps) need to download big runtime parts. You should learn more about them before actually using them. And you can choice - do you want to waste disk space and network traffic to use them, or not.

Some developer applications are available in [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make).

---

In your particular case - GIMP needs to download GNOME runtime (`runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.28`) and dependencies (check [flatpak  *org.gimp.GIMP.json*](https://github.com/flathub/org.gimp.GIMP/blob/master/org.gimp.GIMP.json) for details):

> ```
> $ flatpak install https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.gimp.GIMP.flatpakref
> The application org.gimp.GIMP depends on runtimes from:
>   https://dl.flathub.org/repo/
> Configure this as new remote 'flathub' [y/n]: y
> Required runtime for org.gimp.GIMP/x86_64/stable (runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.28) found in remote flathub
> Do you want to install it? [y/n]: y
> Installing in system:
> org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.28             flathub 6d1d0ebbd724
> org.freedesktop.Platform.ffmpeg/x86_64/1.6 flathub d757f762489e
> org.gnome.Platform.Locale/x86_64/3.28      flathub 2823e3d81b74
> org.gimp.GIMP/x86_64/stable                flathub 1fcb2c783cf6
>   permissions: ipc, network, x11
>   file access: /tmp, host, xdg-config/GIMP, xdg-config/gtk-3.0
>   dbus access: org.gtk.vfs, org.gtk.vfs.*
>   tags: stable
> Is this ok [y/n]: n
> ```

Here there is one positive moment - this runtime may be reused by other later installed FlatPaks.

---

Personally I prefer PPAs over Snaps and Flatpaks and install several applications from `umake` (for example Arduino IDE).

Answer (score 0):

For now GIMP command forcing us to download also a Manual pack, which is shows 800+MB size to download...

```
$ flatpak install https://flathub.org/repo/appstream/org.gimp.GIMP.flatpakref 
The remote 'flathub', referred to by 'org.gimp.GIMP' at location https://dl.flathub.org/repo/ contains additional applications.
Should the remote be kept for future installations? [Y/n]: y
Required runtime for org.gimp.GIMP/x86_64/stable (runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.36) found in remote flathub
Do you want to install it? [Y/n]: y

org.gimp.GIMP permissions:
    ipc           network      x11      dri      file access [1]      dbus access [2]
    tags [3]

    [1] /tmp, host, xdg-config/GIMP, xdg-config/gtk-3.0, xdg-run/gvfs
    [2] org.freedesktop.FileManager1, org.gtk.vfs, org.gtk.vfs.*
    [3] stable


        ID                                             Ветка      Op     Удалённый репозиторий     Download
 1.     org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default            19.08      i      flathub                    < 89,1 MB
 2.     org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-390-138     1.4        i      flathub                    < 48,9 MB
 3.     org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel           19.08      i      flathub                     < 8,7 MB
 4.     org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264              2.0        i      flathub                     < 1,5 MB
 5.     org.gimp.GIMP.Manual                           2.10       i      flathub                   < 876,5 MB
 6.     org.gnome.Platform.Locale                      3.36       i      flathub                   < 323,1 MB (partial)
 7.     org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Pop-dark                     3.22       i      flathub                   < 226,0 kB
 8.     org.gnome.Platform                             3.36       i      flathub                   < 326,0 MB
 9.     org.gimp.GIMP                                  stable     i      flathub                   < 116,3 MB

Proceed with these changes to the system installation? [Y/n]:
```

I was surprised and i asked about it In GIMP IRC channel, and here is what guys told me:

> ... actually by default, it will in fact only install the current locale. Yet it will still show the huge 800+MB value
> `du -sh /home/$USER/.local/share/flatpak/runtime/org.gimp.GIMP.Manual/x86_64/2.10/active/`
> 64M

I tested to install GIMP flatpak and here is the download process:

```
        ID                                             Ветка      Op     Удалённый репозиторий     Download
 1. [✓] org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default            19.08      i      flathub                      88,6 MB / 89,1 MB
 2. [✓] org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-390-138     1.4        i      flathub                      48,8 MB / 48,9 MB
 3. [✓] org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel           19.08      i      flathub                       8,6 MB / 8,7 MB
 4. [✓] org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264              2.0        i      flathub                       1,5 MB / 1,5 MB
 5. [✓] org.gimp.GIMP.Manual                           2.10       i      flathub                      49,0 MB / 876,5 MB
 6. [✓] org.gnome.Platform.Locale                      3.36       i      flathub                       3,7 MB / 323,1 MB
 7. [✓] org.gtk.Gtk3theme.Pop-dark                     3.22       i      flathub                     226,3 kB / 226,0 kB
 8. [\] org.gnome.Platform                             3.36       i      flathub                      17,7 MB / 326,0 MB
 9. [ ] org.gimp.GIMP
```

Thus, it seems that flatpak does not show the actual size before download start.